# Can I do a find/replace in t-sql?

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql

I basically have an xml column, and I need to find and replace one tag value in each record.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

For anything real, I'd go with xpaths, but sometimes you just need a quick and dirty solution:

You can use CAST to turn that xml column into a regular varchar, and then do your normal replace.

`UPDATE xmlTable SET xmlCol = REPLACE( CAST( xmlCol as varchar(max) ), '[search]', '[replace]')`

That same technique also makes searching XML a snap when you need to just run a quick query to find something, and don't want to deal with xpaths.

`SELECT * FROM xmlTable WHERE CAST( xmlCol as varchar(max) ) LIKE '%found it!%'`

Edit: Just want to update this a bit, if you get a message along the lines of *Conversion of one or more characters from XML to target collation impossible*, then you only need to use nvarchar which supports unicode.

`CAST( xmlCol as nvarchar(max) )`

Comment: @Cory-Mawhorter You mentioned XPath would be "better". How would you use XPath to change something in the XML column?

Comment: @ArminderDahul It has been a while but I think you can do it like `set xmlCol.nodes('/somenode/someothernode[@id=sql:variable("@somevar")]/text') = 'blah'`.  Not sure.  Michael's answer might get you started.

Answer (score 16):

To find a content in an XML column, look into the exist() method, as described in MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869(SQL.90).aspx).

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE XMLColumn.exist('/Root/MyElement') = 1
```

...to replace, use the modify() method, as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190675(SQL.90).aspx).

```
SET XMLColumn.modify('
  replace value of (/Root/MyElement/text())[1]
  with "new value"
')
```

..all assuming SqlServer 2005 or 2008.  This is based on XPath, which you'll need to know.

Answer (score -5):

```
update my_table
set xml_column = replace(xml_column, "old  value", "new value")
```

Comment: "Argument data type xml is invalid for argument 1 of replace fuction"