# TSQL 2005, XML DML - Update Two Values at once?

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005, t-sql, dml, xml-dml

Is there any way to combine these two replace values with 1 update statement?

```
UPDATE dbo.MyTable
SET MyXmlColumn.modify('replace value of (/node/@att1)[1] with "1"')
WHERE id = 1

UPDATE dbo.MyTable
SET MyXmlColumn.modify('replace value of (/node/@att2)[1] with "2"')
WHERE id = 1
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms190675(v=SQL.90).aspx

Comment: Check out the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395942/updating-multiple-xml-nodes-using-t-sql.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I dont think you're in luck, Thx.

I tried several syntactical variants with no joy.  For example, the obvious:

```
SET MyXmlColumn.modify('...'), MyXmlColumn.modify('...')
```

yields:

> The column name 'MyXmlColumn' is specified more than once in the SET
>   clause. A column cannot be assigned more than one value in the same
>   SET clause. Modify the SET clause to make sure that a column is
>   updated only once. If the SET clause updates columns of a view, then
>   the column name 'MyXmlColumn' may appear twice in the view
>   definition.

But there's nothing helpful for this error message in the XML DML space.

The bottom line is that Expression1 & Expression2 must be single elements.

Even the most thorough discussions end up looping through it...

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/denisruc/archive/2005/09/19/471562.aspx

Sorry.  :(

PS: If you can stand the hackiness, casting to VARCHAR(MAX) then doing a normal REPLACE() should do the trick.  See: [Can I do a find/replace in t-sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171412/can-i-do-a-find-replace-in-t-sql)

Answer (score 2):

No, as stated in the documentation, `replace value of` can only operate on a single node at one time. As far as I know, there isn't a workaround for this. You'll need to use 2 update statements.

Comment: "Note that the target being updated must be, at most, one node that is explicitly specified in the path expression by adding a "[1]" at the end of the expression."
I took this to mean my xpath can only return 1 node, not whether I can have two replace value of statements each targetting 1 node

Answer (score 1):

If you just have a couple of values you want to change you could use this approach I found at [sqlservercentral](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1088662-145-1.aspx). It uses a select statement to get the data manipulates it multiple times and uses a single update statement to change the table data.

Not perfect but it might be good enough in some use cases. Basically it is a simplified version of the looping solution for a fixed number of values to change.

```
DECLARE @temp XML
SET @temp = (SELECT Column_name FROM Table_name WHERE AuthId = @AuthId)

SET @temp.modify('replace value of (/UmAuthDto/Assignment/QueueId/text())[1] with sql:variable("@NewValue")') 
SET @temp.modify('replace value of (/UmAuthDto/Assignment/QueueName/text())[1] with sql:variable("@NewValue")')

UPDATE Table_name
SET Column_name = @temp
WHERE AuthId = @AuthId
```