# Update Multiple Values In Xml with .modify method

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have looked over release documentation for the `2012 SP1` release of `Sql Server`

and reviewed this old post.

[TSQL 2005, XML DML - Update Two Values at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327440/tsql-2005-xml-dml-update-two-values-at-once)

I am wondering is it possible to update multiple `values` now, or do you still need multiple update statements for the `.modify` method.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there's been any significant improvements in capabilities for the `.modify()` XQuery method in more recent releases

Comment: marc_s, make your reply a answer. so I can give you the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's been any significant improvements in capabilities for the `.modify()` XQuery method in more recent releases. So I'm afraid you still cannot update multiple values at once - you'll have to use multiple calls to `.modify()`